# Styling all roads to highlight their outline?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an "outline-only" map where the inside of the road is all white and the "sidewalk" outline colored black. For example, I want 14th St and 5th Ave to look just like every other minor street. (pardon the ugly sketch)

[image: new york streets]

I'm using the [Style Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)  and it was easy to get local roads to look like that, but I'm stuck getting the arterial and highways to match the local look. They're either all grayish or all black, and there's little or no outline visible. On the default style and max zoom I can see one pixel of outline in a light gray, but nothing after applying a style.

Here's a [live page](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/geocodingprint.html) and the styles I'm using

```
[
  {
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -100 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.local",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#ffe500" },
      { saturation: -45 },
      { gamma: 0.09 },
      { lightness: 12 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.highway",
    elementType: "geometry",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#ffee00" },
      { invert_lightness: true },
      { saturation: -49 },
      { lightness: 99 },
      { gamma: 0.9 }
    ]
  },{
    featureType: "road.arterial",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#0008ff" },
      { saturation: -95 },
      { lightness: -15 },
      { gamma: 0.94 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to style all roads with a black outline and a white fill. The accepted answer is out-of-date.

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ffffff" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#000000" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't work on arterial roads though. I've tried it like 10x and can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As of current, this is no longer possible again and is currently marked as a bug. (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10197) I spent a long time trying to figure out why this wasn't working and so thought I could save someone some time by posting here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you're trying to do is possible. I played around with the styling wizard, and it appears that despite it appearing as if there is an outline on arterial and highway roads, there's isn't really or it is not visible after applying styles.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I think I can live with gray roads